# UICollectionViewCell cellforItemAt: with array

Tags: swift

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        var cell: DoctorInfoCollectionViewCell

        print("Cell now = \(cellNow)")

        cell = cvDoctorInfo.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "DoctorInfo", for: indexPath) as! DoctorInfoCollectionViewCell

        if indexPath.row == 0
        {
            cell.imgInfoIcon.image = UIImage(named: "doctordomain")

            cell.lblInfoTitle.text = "Domain"
            cell.lblInfoDesc.text = thisDoctor.domain

            cellNow = "education"
            return cell
        }

        else if cellNow == "education"
        {
            for education in thisDoctor.education!
            {
            cell.imgInfoIcon.image = UIImage(named: "education")

            cell.lblInfoTitle.text = "Education"
            cell.lblInfoDesc.text = education

            educationCount = educationCount - 1

            if educationCount == 0
            {
               cellNow = "hospital"
            }

            return cell

            }
        }


        else if cellNow == "hospital"
        {
            for hospital in thisDoctor.location!
            {
            cell.imgInfoIcon.image = UIImage(named: "locationlogo")

            cell.lblInfoTitle.text = "Working Hospital"
            cell.lblInfoDesc.text = (hospital.value as! String)

            cellNow = "phone"
            return cell
            }
        }

        else if cellNow == "phone"
        {
            cell.imgInfoIcon.image = UIImage(named: "phoneicon")

            cell.lblInfoTitle.text = "Contact Number"
            cell.lblInfoDesc.text = thisDoctor.phone

            cellNow = "email"
            return cell
        }

        else if cellNow == "email"
        {
            cell.imgInfoIcon.image = UIImage(named: "email")

            cell.lblInfoTitle.text = "Email"
            cell.lblInfoDesc.text = thisDoctor.email

            cellNow = "socialplatform"
            return cell
        }

        else if cellNow == "socialplatform"
        {
        for socialplatform in thisDoctor.socialplatform!
        {
            cell.imgInfoIcon.image = UIImage(named: "socialmedialink")

            cell.lblInfoTitle.text = "Other Social Platform"
            cell.lblInfoDesc.text = socialplatform

            socialPlatformCount = socialPlatformCount - 1

            if socialPlatformCount == 0
            {
                cellNow = ""
            }

            return cell
        }

        }

        return cell

    }
```

For the first run everything seems ok, but then when I scroll up and down the arrangement become a mess, for instance row 2 and 3 and 4 suddenly became education cell. Is there anyway to handle this? I know it is related to the reusable but I have no idea how to handle it.

`cellNow` is a variable initialized to "" when the user navigate to this view.

Comment: Be aware that `cellForItem` is called **once** fro each item. Therefore the arrays make no sense because the `lblInfoDesc` value gets overwritten in each iteration. Regarding the *mess*: Basically you have to ensure that any UI element is set to a defined state as the cells are reused.

Comment: i have return the numberofrowincomponent to all the array count  + the base row needed

Comment: so the best solution is to create multiple UIviewcollection to handle each array?

Comment: This depends on what you are going to accomplish. It might be sufficient to create a comma separated string from the items in the array.

Comment: Post the ui screenshot and your array or model